# How to export matlab matrix to .txt in a format supported by c

Tags: c, matlab, export

As I state in the title, I want to export a matrix from matlab to a  `.txt` file in format that is supported by C. What I mean is something like this

```
{ { 1, 2, 3, 4}, { 5, 6, 7, 8} ...... }
```

Any suggestions ?

Edit. I used this loop and it seems that it did the trick very nicely.
Thanks for the help :)

```
  for (row = 0;row < XLENGTH ; row++)                   
  {   
      for(column=0;column<YLENGTH;column++) 
      { 
          fscanf(fr, "%d " ",", &num);
          Image_input[row][column]=num;
      }     
  }
```

Comment: How about: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use [jsonencode()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) to turn a matrix into the same string format as you want albeit with [] instead of {}. You could then use [regexprep()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to replace the brackets and [fprintf()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to write to a file.

That said you could definitely write a function in c using [fscanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) and use Matlab's writematrix as others suggested to do something far neater, and probably slightly faster as regexprep will add time.